# How to get twitter screen name in Firebase auth

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

Hi I am not sure how to get twitter screen name from getprovidersData() as it is returning a List and when I iterated the List it give data like

> D/Twitter Data:: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafv@4f19ea4
>   D/Twitter Data:: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafv@eb40d

```
    List proData = mFirebaseUser.getProviderData();
    for (Object ui:proData
         ) {
        Log.d("Twitter Data:",ui.toString());
    }
```

How will I get twitter use screen name from that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This code is derived from the example provided in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_a_users_provider-specific_profile_information).  Please try running it after you have signed in with Twitter to see if the display name is the screen name you are expecting.

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

if (user != null) {
    for (UserInfo profile : user.getProviderData()) {
        if (profile.getProviderId().equals(TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID)) {
            // UID specific to the provider
            String uid = profile.getUid();

            // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
            String name = profile.getDisplayName();
            String email = profile.getEmail();
            Uri photoUrl = profile.getPhotoUrl();
            Log.i("DEBUG", String.format("uid=%s name=%s email=%s url=%s",
                    uid, name, email, photoUrl));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is fine but I want to get twitter screen name out of getProviderData()..as this is given in firebase documentation [fbdoc](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/login/twitter.html)  i.e. getProviderData().get("username")

Comment: The link in your comment is to the documentation for the legacy SDK, 2.X.  Is that what you are building with?  Not the new 9.X SDK?

Comment: No no I am building with 9.X SDK when I googled how to get twitter screen name it came as result. But still with new SDK it is not mentioned how to get twitter specific data here I need user screen name, any idea @qbix?

Comment: @amitsrivastava:  I updated my answer, please try running that code.

Comment: I figured it out with using active TwitterSession, TwitterSession session = Twitter.getSessionManager().getActiveSession(); session.getUserName(); to get twitter screen name. getUid() is returning unique id provided by twiiter not username, thanks for your time @qbix

Comment: thanks, that was really helpful amit, I couldn't get the username for firebase as well and that did it, I just needed to use the twitter apk

Answer (score 2):

You need 4 things to get twitter user details including screen_name.

1. Consumer Key
2. Consumer Secret
3. Access Token
4. Token Secret

1 and 2 you can get from twitter app dashboard.

3 and 4 will be given in `signInSuccessWithAuthResult` callback function in `authResult` object when a user successfully signed in using firebase auth.
These 4 should go in header request for GET api call -> https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json

more info on this: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/manage-account-settings/api-reference/get-account-verify_credentials

### To use in node.js app:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter

### To test out using postman:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Or just call `https://api.twitter.com/2/users/$userID` with your Bearer in your header